# Is Volume in Docker a security hole?

Tags: security, docker, volume

If we expose a host directory using 'volume' in a docker container. I am wondering whether that is that considered a security back door.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone who can run a container on your system and mount a volume can do anything `root` can do. The simplest way to accomplish this is to mount `/` inside the container, so then as root in the container you can change any file on the host.

But I would not consider that a security back door any more than I would consider `sudo` a security back door.

A couple of good places to review `docker` security are:

- https://docs.docker.com/articles/security/
- https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security

Answer (score 2):

It is not considered a security back door. Any volumes from the host machine exposed to the docker container should abide by the permissions suitable for your execution environment, but there isn't a way for example to traverse directories and expose `/etc/passwd` or things of this nature. At the end of the day, your container exists as data on the host machine anyways (in `/var/lib/docker` -- check for yourself). If you have more specific worries, update your question and I'll address them, but as is no, this is not considered a security backdoor.

Comment: `docker run --rm -it -v /:/hostRoot alpine:latest head -n 1 /hostRoot/etc/passwd`